# What is the correct way to import a NPM module

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading, npm, npm-install

I ran 'npm install p-queue --save'. I found "p-queue": "^7.1.0" in the package.json file. In main.js file, I import p-queue by using 'const PQueue = require('p-queue');' But I got these error messages

```
App threw an error during load
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module:
require() of ES modules is not supported.
```

Then I import p-queue by using 'import PQueue from 'p-queue';'. The error message is

```
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

I want to know what is the correct way to import p-queue module? I hope someone can help me solve this issue.

Thanks!

Comment: have you set `"type": "module"` in your `package.json`?

Comment: Which package.json file? There is one package.json in root directory. In node_modules/p-queue folder, there is a package.json file. Which package.json do I need to change?

Comment: **your** one, not the one that came from any module

Comment: I added "type": "module" in package.json in root directory. Then the main.js in root directory becomes a ES module. The error is node_modules/electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/Resources/default_app.asar/main.js requires main.js in root directory, but main.js is a ES module, It recommends me to remove "type": "module" from package.json. Could you tell me what should I do next?